# Queries at the same time using MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm designing a chat application using AJAX, PHP, MySQL and am having a problem.

MySQL table is like this `username[varchar11]-taken[enum-0,1](coloumns)` generally a user who wants to talk to userX, firstly checks if taken value of `userx` is `0` or  `1`

```
SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE username=userX
```

If it is `0` the user updates taken as `1`:

```
UPDATE usertable SET taken=1 WHERE username=userX
```

and starts to talk to userX.

But when there are two users who want to talk to `userX` and check the taken value at the same time unconsciously, they both get `0` response. As a result of it, both of their updates are taken as `1` afterwards and start to talk to `userX` at the same time. Effectively, 3 users will be talking each other. This chat site is supposed to allow a user to talk to maximum one user at the same time. I'm trying to design it like that.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. What I need is something which is going to stop other users from checking and updating taken value until one finishes to check and update taken value.

Comment: Sounds like you're referring to what we call race conditions! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_conditions

Comment: i am not that familiar with electronic with electronics and hardware.however, it sounds similar to mine as far as i understand

Comment: The same goes for software too. Thread safety is a good place to start, as are synchronized methods/functions, and table locking. Those are some strategies to help deal with race conditions. Chat applications have a very high chance of being subject to these events.

Comment: thanks i'll check them out is there anything else?

Comment: Well, you've only posted so much code, so I can't see exactly what's going on. Given this has a PHP tag, here is a good starting point, as I'm assuming you might want to do this in a multithreaded environment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/thread.synchronized.php